# How to determin what type of resource is being requested within AuthenticateRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way of working out whether or not a requested resource supports POST data before the request has been authenticated?

In my HttpMoudle, within the `AuthenticateRequest` event, I am checking whether or not the path ends with ".aspx" but this feels crude and doesn't work for routed URLs.

I had explored checking the type of `HttpContext.Current.Handler` but this is not assigned until later in the event chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET doesn't know anything about what handler the request should be mapped to until the [`HttpApplication.PostMapRequestHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postmaprequesthandler.aspx) event. It's the *ideal* place to know which handler will be executed. Subscribing to the [`HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest.aspx) event ensures that the request will be authenticated before processing the attached module or event handler only.

So the only way you can do it within the `AuthenticateRequest` event, is to analyze the URL (as you do), I think.